# Elasticsearch search index limit by type

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, types, limit

I am new to elasticsearch and I am trying to use elasticsearch, search api.

My index structure consists of tree types. Say `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. All tree types have the same 'name' key with string values and what I am trying to achieve is to search all types but just retrieve max 5 items of each type.

I think I succeed with Multi Search API however; I wonder if I could maintain the same functionality with a single query instead (for better performance).

I searched the internet as much as I can. However, I couldn't find a better way. There is an answer in stackoverflow with a similar question which also offers multi search api; but is two years old and with an issue attached to it. I thought It is meaningful to ask again.

Here is the msearch I am using at the moment:

```
{"type" : "foo"}
{"query" : {"match": {"name": "bar"}}, "terminate_after": 5}
{"type" : "bar"}
{"query" : {"match": {"name": "bar"}}, "terminate_after": 5}
{"type" : "baz"}
{"query" : {"match": {"name": "bar"}}, "terminate_after": 5}
```

I think that will check all storage 3 times if I write a query with max 4 results.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the underlying reason why you want to change your multi-search query if it works? Is it too slow?

Comment: @Val You know, that's an engineering problem. I'm trying to optimize as well as I know and can.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just curious ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation using `_type` and then find top 5 from each:

```
GET /index/_search 
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
  "match": {
     "name": "bar"
   }
},
"aggs": {
  "group_by_type": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "top_5_aggregation": {
            "top_hits":{
                "size" :5
             }
          }
       }
     }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Very nice, clean, 'copy - paste - watch it working' answer. Thanks.